# How can I access to a .properties file situated outside the project folder and outside the project classpath?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, properties, inputstream, java-ee-6

I have the following problem trying to retrieve a **config.properties** file situated outside my project root directory.

So I have a situation like this:

```
CONTAINER DIRECTORY
     |
     |
     |------> config.properties
     |
     |
     |------>PROJECT-ROOT
                 |
                 |
                 |
                 |------> src
                     |
                     |
                     |------> mainPkg (the package name)
                                 |
                                 |
                                 |------> Main (the main class containing the main() method)
```

From the **main()** method situated inside the **Main** class I have to access to the **config.properties** file that is at the same level of the project root folder (and that is out of the project classpath).

I have to use **relative path** so I have to do something like this: starting from a folder inside the project I have to come back untill the **CONTAINER DIRECTORY** and here take the **config.properties** file

How can I do it? (I am under Windows environment)

Answer (score 2):

I think, in your situation, it's best to use the [Classloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) your Class provides.

It should work like this:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("config.properties");
```

The only problem is, you can't compile that code in a static method like main.
If you want to run it in a static method, you should change it to:

```
Main.class.getClassLoader().getResources("config.properties");
```